# 「黄米来夏」 Can this be considered a name?

Tags: kanji, pronunciation, readings, names

I am attempting to make a name for a character and decided on these 4 kanji. My question is, can this be considered a name in Japanese, if so, how would it be pronounced?

Comment: Where does it come from? Especially the 黄米 part, why 黄米?

Comment: No other reason than I wanted to include the kanji for rice, adding 黄 was just for a bit of decoration. The character is from a farming family, and when I looked up 黄米 it was associated with millet.

Comment: 黄米 is not a surname that seems to occur, though both 黄 as first element and 米 as second definitely happen. Not really sure what the reading would be (maybe a really fancy way to spell こめ, using bound form of 黄 and man'yogana reading for 米). However, 来夏 is definitely known as a female name.

Comment: @AlexanderZ. I agree. I asked OP why they chose that word 黄米 also because I don't think that's a word in Japanese. OP seems to have Chinese and Japanese words mixed up

Comment: @EddieKal But in Chinese, millet is 小米 not 黄米...

Answer (score 1):

This might be an interesting read for you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinmeiy%C5%8D_kanji (Note that this list is supplementary, but that there are laws regarding what people can and cannot name their children.)

My dictionary lists 来夏 as being a female name with the pronunciations of こなつ, らいか, らいな, and らな. No hits on the first two kanji.